# Wordpress Role Custom Capability is set true but returns false

Tags: wordpress, user-roles

I try to create a user role with some custom capabilities. That works so far. But if I want to check the user permissions of one specific capability with the function `current_user_can()` it returns false. But inside the capabilities array of the new created role the specific capability is set to true.

So to give my words a little bit more coding background:
**THE ROLE OBJECT**

```
WP_Role {
  ["name"]=> "organizer"
  ["capabilities"]=> {
       ["edit_posts"]              => bool(false)
       ["delete_posts"]            => bool(false)
       ["publish_posts"]           => bool(false)
       ["upload_files"]            => bool(true)
       ["edit_event"]              => bool(true)
       ["read_event"]              => bool(true)
       ["delete_event"]            => bool(true)
       ["edit_events"]             => bool(true)
       ["edit_others_events"]      => bool(false)
       ["publish_events"]          => bool(false)
       ["read_private_events"]     => bool(true)
       ["read"]                    => bool(true)
       ["delete_events"]           => bool(true)
       ["delete_private_events"]   => bool(false)
       ["delete_published_events"] => bool(true)
       ["delete_others_events"]    => bool(false)
       ["edit_private_events"]     => bool(false)
       ["edit_published_events"]   => bool(true)
       ["manage_event_terms"]      => bool(true)
       ["edit_event_terms"]        => bool(true)
       ["delete_event_terms"]      => bool(true)
       ["assign_event_terms"]      => bool(true)
  }
```

**MY ADD ROLE FUNCTION**

```
add_role( 'organizer', __( 'Organizer', 'eventtool' ), array(
            // General
            'edit_posts'              => false,
            'delete_posts'            => false,
            'publish_posts'           => false,
            'upload_files'            => true,
            'edit_event'              => true,
            'read_event'              => true,
            'delete_event'            => true,

            // Primitive capabilities used outside of map_meta_cap():
            'edit_events'             => true,
            'edit_others_events'      => false,
            'publish_events'          => false,
            'read_private_events'     => true,

            // Primitive capabilities used within map_meta_cap():
            'read'                    => true,
            'delete_events'           => true,
            'delete_private_events'   => false,
            'delete_published_events' => true,
            'delete_others_events'    => false,
            'edit_private_events'     => false,
            'edit_published_events'   => true,
            'edit_events'             => true,

            // Terms
            'manage_event_terms'      => true,
            'edit_event_terms'        => true,
            'delete_event_terms'      => true,
            'assign_event_terms'      => true
        )
);
```

**CUSTOM POST TYPE ARGS**

```
register_post_type( 'event', array(
                'labels'              => $labels,
                'description'         => __( 'This is where you can add new events to your page.', 'eventtool' ),
                'public'              => true,
                'show_ui'             => true,
                'capability_type'     => 'event',
                'map_meta_cap'        => true,
                'publicly_queryable'  => true,
                'exclude_from_search' => false,
                'hierarchical'        => false,
                'rewrite'             => _x( 'event', 'slug', 'eventtool' ),
                'query_var'           => true,
                'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail' ),
                'show_in_nav_menus'   => true
            )
        );
```

[UPDATE]

```
function et_modify_map_meta_cap( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ) {

    var_dump($cap)

}
add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'et_modify_map_meta_cap', 10, 4 );
```

Outputs 'edit_post' instead of 'edit_event'

Any suggestions, why this wrong behaviour comes up?

Comment: You're not showing where you're using `current_user_can`... and what does the filter `map_meta_cap` has to do with this? . . . My `var_dump($cap)` shows `edit_events` all right...

Comment: Thank you brasofilo. Your response has led me to think outside the box. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I solved it.

It is neccessary to assign an object id for the second parameter to the `current_user_can()` function to get the correct return of single pointed capabilities (eg. 'edit_post'). Otherwise the function will return false, if this parameter is not set.

As inside the [WordPress Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can):

> If omitted you may receive an 'Undefined offset: 0' warning (this is because the `current_user_can` function eventually calls `map_meta_cap` which when checking against meta capabilities expects an array but is only supplied a single value)

Answer (score 0):

Try to register these `capabilities` to the custom post type `event` first , and then assign those `capabilities` to `organiser`

Like this :

```
function create_my_post_types() {
    register_post_type(
        'movie',
        array(
            'public' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'movie',
            'capabilities' => array(
                'publish_posts' => 'publish_movies',
                'edit_posts' => 'edit_movies',
                'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_movies',
                'delete_posts' => 'delete_movies',
                'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_movies',
                'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_movies',
                'edit_post' => 'edit_movie',
                'delete_post' => 'delete_movie',
                'read_post' => 'read_movie',
            ),
        )
    );
}
```

Change the code to `event` post type.

And check the user capababilities by below code instead :

```
add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'my_map_meta_cap', 10, 4 );

function my_map_meta_cap( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ) {

    /* If editing, deleting, or reading a movie, get the post and post type object. */
    if ( 'edit_movie' == $cap || 'delete_movie' == $cap || 'read_movie' == $cap ) {
        $post = get_post( $args[0] );
        $post_type = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );

        /* Set an empty array for the caps. */
        $caps = array();
    }

    /* If editing a movie, assign the required capability. */
    if ( 'edit_movie' == $cap ) {
        if ( $user_id == $post->post_author )
            $caps[] = $post_type->cap->edit_posts;
        else
            $caps[] = $post_type->cap->edit_others_posts;
    }

    /* If deleting a movie, assign the required capability. */
    elseif ( 'delete_movie' == $cap ) {
        if ( $user_id == $post->post_author )
            $caps[] = $post_type->cap->delete_posts;
        else
            $caps[] = $post_type->cap->delete_others_posts;
    }

    /* If reading a private movie, assign the required capability. */
    elseif ( 'read_movie' == $cap ) {

        if ( 'private' != $post->post_status )
            $caps[] = 'read';
        elseif ( $user_id == $post->post_author )
            $caps[] = 'read';
        else
            $caps[] = $post_type->cap->read_private_posts;
    }

    /* Return the capabilities required by the user. */
    return $caps;
}
```

Comment: 1. To assign an extra `capabilities` array to the `register_post_type` function is not neccessary in this case.
The argument `capability_type` will do this for you. It's necessary if you have the post type 'memory' for example.
Then it would autogenerates `edit_others_memorys` instead of `edit_others_memories`. Therefore you can ajust that inside the `capabilities` argument

Comment: 2. That won't work. The capabilities are set to the organiser and be inside the database of WordPress, so it doesn't matter if I add the capabilities before or after the `register_post_type` function to the role.
What matters is that they are set inside the Role Object and they are.

Answer (score 0):

Try [user_can()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/user_can). You will need to pass the user ID as first parameter. You can get it through [get_current_user_id()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_user_id).

Comment: That will also return false, because `user_can()` and `get_current_user_id()` are calling the same function to check the capability 

[See here, Line 501](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.1/src/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L501)

`return call_user_func_array( array( $user, 'has_cap' ), $args );`

Comment: Then you have two ways to do it. First, treat WP_Role as an OOP object and check if a certain element exists in the 'capabilities' property array. Or you can check through $wpdp query.